# How do I preserve a string and prevent it from being destroyed when passing it to an action script block?

Tags: powershell, events

For example,

```
$foo = 'bar'
$eventArgs = @{
  ...
  Action = {
    Write-Host "Should be foo, but it's empty: $foo"
  }
}
Register-ObjectEvent @eventArgs
```

---

There must be some way to completely copy over the string into the Action Block. How is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`MessageData` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.3#-messagedata) to pass arbitrary data to the Action block, a simple example:

```bash
$col = [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[int]]::new()
$registerObjectEventSplat = @{
    InputObject = $col
    EventName   = 'Completed'
    Action      = {
        'Collection {0}' -f $event.MessageData | Out-Host
    }
    MessageData = 'completed yay'
}
$evt = Register-ObjectEvent @registerObjectEventSplat
$col.Complete() # Callback -> `Collection completed yay`
```

---

Side note: Try to avoid using [`$EventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#eventargs) as your variable name as it is an automatic variable.